# error: Object cannot be converted to String

Tags: java, hashmap

Does anyone have any help with this error?

```
error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String
```

I am passing a `HashMap` into a function with the intention of iterating through its keyset and storing them into a list for ordering, here is my code

```java
public HashMap mapReorder(HashMap map) {

    /* Clear the list ready for input */
    mapList.clear();

    /* Iterate through the keys in the map */

    for(String keys : map.keySet()) {
        double mapKey = keys.getValue();
        mapList.add(mapKey);
    }

    /* Sorting the order by ascending value (Internal Frequency Rank) */
    Collections.sort(mapList);

    /* Populating HashMap with ordered list */
    for(double frequencies : mapList) {
        orderedMap.put(keys , frequencies);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Have you googled your error message ? You will find your answer.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Answer (score 2):

the line with `for(String keys : map.keySet())` is causing the error.

`Map.keySet()` returns a `Set<Object>` and not a `Set<String>` because you're using rawTypes (`HashMap`). So change either the line to:

```
for(Object keys : map.keySet())
```

or change the signature of your method to following:

```
public HashMap<String, ValueType> mapReorder(HashMap<String,ValueType> map){
```

where `ValueType` is the type of value stored in your `map`

Comment: This is wrong. You can use the enhanced loop to iterate over a `Set`.

Comment: @MuratK. sorry had a brainfart. see the edit

Answer (score -2):

> I am passing a hashmap into a function with the intention of
>   iterating through its keyset and storing them into a list for
>   ordering

`HashMap` is not ordered. So you better use `TreeMap` which is sorted according to natural ordering of its keys.

```
return new TreeMap(map)
```

Comment: This does not even answer the question remotely.

Comment: I offer a better way @MuratK. The code in question is wrong. The TS want to sort the map, using `HashMap` which is not sorted.

Comment: I'm waiting for one more downvote :)